# How to get individual character from varchar columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with this data:

```
ID  | Data
----+-----
1   | ABC
2   | A
3   | A
4   | AC
5   | B
```

I would like to extract for each row each character and the ID from it come like this:

```
ID  | Data_extract
----+-----------
1   | A
1   | B
1   | C
2   | A
3   | A
4   | A
4   | C
5   | B
```

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Common table expressions to achieve this.

```sql
DECLARE @t table(ID int, val VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES 
(1   ,'ABC')
,(2   ,'A')
,(3   ,'A')
,(4   ,'AC')
,(5   ,'B');

;WITH CTE_VAL AS
(
SELECT id, 
cast((case when len(val) > 1 then left(val,1) else val end) as nvarchar(50)) as nval, 1 as lvl
from @t
UNION ALL
SELECT t.id,
cast(substring(val,lvl+1,1) as nvarchar(50)) as nval, lvl+1
FROM @t AS t INNER JOIN CTE_VAL AS c
ON t.ID = c.ID
WHERE len(val) > 1 and lvl < len(val)
)
SELECT id,nval FROM CTE_VAL
order by id
```

```
+----+------+
| id | nval |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
|  1 | B    |
|  1 | C    |
|  2 | A    |
|  3 | A    |
|  4 | A    |
|  4 | C    |
|  5 | B    |
+----+------+
```